# Optimizing large excel report

Tags: vba, excel

I'm looking for any advices, that could help me optimize report.

Report consists of pivot table, that pulls data from other spreadsheet. Data in pivot table is colored and grouped by VBA macros.
My main concern is exactly coloring and grouping.

I have to color most of line's backgrounds and then I have to group them. I'm reading all rows from table with data, then I'm cutting-pasting 5 columns with hierarchy that defines line coloring and grouping rules. I'm checking row by row if values are matching in columns.

Example of hierarchy:

```
CoreElement Category    Subcategory     Code    Product
6           26          161             1289    3014659
6           26          161             1245    3014655
6           26          161             1289    3014585
6           26          161             1282    3019640
7           28          164             164     164
7           7           7               7       7
7           7           7               7       7
5           22          142             1208    1208
5           22          142             142     142
```

Coloring:

```
Set oColor = Worksheets("Category_Sales").Range("A13:A" & MaxLineNumber + 13)
For Each CellId In oColor.Cells
k = CellId.Column
r = CellId.Row

    If Cells(r, 64).Value = "-1" Then 'Store Sales
            Range("A" & r & ":AV" & r).Interior.Color = RGB(204, 255, 204)
            Range("A" & r & ":AV" & r).Font.Bold = True
    ElseIf Cells(r, 64).Value = Cells(r, 65).Value And Cells(r, 65).Value = Cells(r, 66).Value And Cells(r, 64) <> "" Then 'Core Element
            Range("A" & r & ":AV" & r).Interior.Color = RGB(214, 225, 238)
            Range("A" & r & ":AV" & r).Font.Bold = True
    ElseIf Cells(r, 64).Value <> Cells(r, 65).Value And Cells(r, 65).Value = Cells(r, 66).Value Then 'Category
            Range("A" & r & ":AV" & r).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 204)
    ElseIf Cells(r, 65).Value <> Cells(r, 66).Value And Cells(r, 66).Value = Cells(r, 67).Value Then 'Subcategory
            Range("A" & r & ":AV" & r).Interior.Color = RGB(191, 191, 191)
    ElseIf Cells(r, 66).Value <> Cells(r, 67).Value And Cells(r, 67).Value = Cells(r, 68).Value Then 'BMC
            Range("A" & r & ":AV" & r).Interior.Color = RGB(217, 217, 217)
    Else
            Range("A" & r & ":AV" & r).Interior.Color = xlNone 'Product
    End If

Next CellId
```

And macro that creates two first groupings, macros for rest of groups are almost the same:

```
k = 13
Set oColor = Worksheets("Category_Sales").Range("A13:A" & MaxLineNumber + 13)
For Each CellId In oColor.Cells
r = CellId.Row

    If Cells(r, 64).Value = "-1" Then
            k = k + 1
    ElseIf Cells(r, 64).Value <> Cells(r + 1, 64).Value And Cells(r, 64).Value <> "" Then
            Rows(k & ":" & r - 1).Rows.Group
            k = r + 1
    End If

Next CellId

k = 13
Set oColor = Worksheets("Category_Sales").Range("A13:A" & MaxLineNumber + 13)
For Each CellId In oColor.Cells
r = CellId.Row

    If Cells(r, 65).Value = Cells(r, 64).Value Then
            k = k + 1
    ElseIf Cells(r, 65).Value <> Cells(r + 1, 65).Value And Cells(r, 65).Value <> "" Then
            Rows(k & ":" & r - 1).Rows.Group
            k = r + 1

    End If

Next CellId
```

In table with data I got 22 thousands of rows.
This report is saved as an .xlsb workbook.

Comment: You could use an array for your comparison, quicker than range(x)=range(y), use arrays.  Look in locals window, how `arrVariant=range(a1:a10).value` looks, it wont be much different in syntax to cells really.  Of course, calculation off, screen updating off etc. would help, cant see if you've turned them off.  You could do the 2nd check in the 1st loop using `offset` also maybe, may need k2 not sure what it does without the data.

Comment: Coloring: Can't you use **Conditional Formatting**? Didn't follow the exact details of your question (and hence I might be missing something), but it looks to me that you could pre-defined the coloring rules in your target sheet and drop the function that colors things.

Comment: Hi there. As there are no functionality issues with your code, this post would be better suited to the sister site [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/). You might get a better response on there.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I use in big reports:
Just call OnStart at the beginning of the code and OnEnd at the end.

```
Public Sub OnEnd()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.AskToUpdateLinks = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
    ThisWorkbook.Date1904 = False

    Application.StatusBar = False

End Sub

Public Sub OnStart()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.AskToUpdateLinks = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
    ThisWorkbook.Date1904 = False

    ActiveWindow.View = xlNormalView

End Sub
```